# getJpegSize could not find the size of the image

Tags: javascript, image, pdf, jspdf

I am using [jspdf](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/index.html) and I am trying to show the image in pdf but I am getting an error

> Uncaught Error: getJpegSize could not find the size of the image

I have tried to find the solution over Google but haven't got the answer. I also, checked the documentation but I still not understood

I have tried below code

```js
function generate() {

var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');

var img = new Image()
img.src = 'https://imgv3.fotor.com/images/videoImage/pixelate-Minions-image.jpg'
doc.addImage(img, 'png', 10, 78, 12, 15)

doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

doc.save('Test.pdf');
 }
```

```html
<button id="btnDownload" onclick="generate()"> Download PDF </button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues raised by your code . However the simplest way to test js.PDF code is start with the online demos. and work from there

[image]
[image]

So

- you are using a very very old jsPDF version
- while testing locally offline you need to add before calling

```
// Create a new jsPDF instance
const {jsPDF} = window.jspdf;
```

- there must be no external origins so the image needs to inside the html zone
- your scaling seems undersize, but will let you play with that.

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="btnDownload" onclick="generate()"> Download PDF </button>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-qZvrmS2ekKPF2mSznTQsxqPgnpkI4DNTlrdUmTzrDgektczlKNRRhy5X5AAOnx5S09ydFYWWNSfcEqDTTHgtNA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
function generate() {

// Don't forget, that there are CORS-Restrictions. So if you want to run it without a Server in your Browser you need to transform the image to a dataURL
// Use https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image

imageData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';

// Create a new jsPDF instance
const {jsPDF} = window.jspdf;
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');

var img = new Image()
doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', 10, 78, 12, 15)

doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

doc.save('Test.pdf');
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: too much code in imageData.. What is that?

Comment: I am a little bit confused about where I have to add my image link and how.

Comment: not understood your last comment.... how can I pass the image URL in imageData?

Comment: Actually I am getting the image from the database and I have to pass in imageData.... this is the issue.. where should I add the URL of the image?